# Comparing the elements of two integer arrays in c++

Tags: c++

I have two integer arrays

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
int comparetwoarrays( int array1[], int array2[], int ARRAY_SIZE1, int ARRAY_SIZE2 )

int main ()
{
    int const ARRAY_SIZE = 500;
    int const ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int array1[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int array2[ARRAY_SIZE2];
    comparetwoarrays( array1, array2, ARRAY_SIZE1, ARRAYSIZE2 )
}

int comparetwoarrays( int array1[], int array2[], int ARRAY_SIZE1, int ARRAY_SIZE2 )
{
    int holdsAlike[10] = {0};
    for( int g = 0; g < ARRAY_SIZE2; g++ )
    {
        for ( int t = 0; t < ARRAY_SIZE2; t++ )
        {
            if ( array2[g] == array1[t])
            {
                 holdsAlike[g] = array2[g];
                 cout<<holdsAlike[g];
            }
            for( int w = 0; w < ARRAY_SIZE2; w++ )
            {
                 if( holdsAlike[w] != 0 )
                 cout<<holdsAlike[w];
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to compare the elements of both arrays, and print out the value and the index of the element. Not sure how to go about getting this done. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You have two definitions of `ARRAY_SIZE`. I guess either of ones should be `ARRAY_SIZE2`.

Comment: yea, I was trying to compare the first 10 elements of the bigger array with the smaller array

Comment: This looks like homework. What is your specific question?

Comment: Not obligatory but you get points for it, plus I really wanted to find out how to solve it. Like really badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code what you want. It may be like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int comparetwoarrays( const int array1[], const int array2[], int array_size1, int array_size2 );

int main ()
{
    int const ARRAY_SIZE1 = 500;
    int const ARRAY_SIZE2 = 10;
    int array1[ARRAY_SIZE1] = {0};
    int array2[ARRAY_SIZE2] = {0};

    // set values to the arrays

    comparetwoarrays( array1, array2, 10, ARRAY_SIZE2 );
}

void comparetwoarrays( const int array1[], const int array2[], int array_size1, int array_size2 )
{
    for( int g = 0; g < array_size2; g++ )
    {
        for ( int t = 0; t < array_size1; t++ )
        {
            if ( array2[g] == array1[t])
            {
                if (g == t)
                {
                    cout << "got \"" << array2[g] << "\" at index " << g << "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "got value = " << array2[g] << ", index on array2 = " << g <<", index on array1 = " << t << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to print only elements both index and value are matched:

```
void comparetwoarrays( const int array1[], const int array2[], int array_size1, int array_size2 )
{
    for( int g = 0; g < array_size1 && g < array_size2; g++ )
    {
        if ( array2[g] == array1[g])
        {
            cout << "got \"" << array2[g] << "\" at index " << g << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for each of array1 elements, array 2 changes its index to 0 - 9, until it array one is up to 499 ... .-.

Comment: Code to compare first 10 elements is added.

Comment: I was attempting to create a function that compared two Arrays. It would compare the values in array2 with the first 10 elements of array1. And, like if the elements would match, I wanted it to print “got” as well as the value and index.  Like, if position 1 of both arrays contained the same value, it would print got "value" at index 1.

Comment: If i were to initialize the elements of the two different arrays, it would work.

Comment: int main ()
{
    int const ARRAY_SIZE1 = 500;
    int const ARRAY_SIZE2 = 10;
    int array1[ARRAY_SIZE1] = {0};
    int array2[ARRAY_SIZE2] = {0};

    // set values to the arrays

    for ( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE1; i++ )
    {
        array1[i] *= 2;

    }

    for ( int n = 0; n < ARRAY_SIZE2; n++)
    {
        array2[n] *=4;
    }
    comparetwoarrays( array1, array2, 10, 10 );
}

Comment: Of course it will work with array initialization. Do you know that `0 * 2 == 0` and `0 * 4 == 0`?